# Retorno Estranho mesmo com Async/Await

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

Tenho as seguintes funções em common.js

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
        // error reading value
    }
}

const storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
    } catch (e) {
        // saving error
    }
}

export { getData, storeData }
```

E tenho o seguinte componente funcional Auth.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import axios from 'axios'

import { serverLogin, showError, storeData, getData } from '../common'

console.log(getData())

const initialState =
{
    email: '',
    password: '',
    save: false
}

export default props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

    const signin = async () => {
        try {
            storeData(state)

            const res = await axios.post(serverLogin, {
                email: state.email,
                password: state.password
            })

            props.onStoreToken(res.data.token)
        } catch (e) {
            showError(e)
        }
    }

    return ( 
       ...
    )

}
```

Como podem ver acima, coloquei um console.log(getData()) para verificar o conteúdo salvo no AsyncStorage, mas só recebo esse retorno estranho:

```
{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
```

Pelo que pesquisei isso está relacionado a um tratamento errôneo com o async/await, mas não consigo localizar em que parte do código. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Descobri a solução para o problema em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798588/reactnative-asyncstorage-returns-weird-values

Parece que eu tenho que usar o async/await também na chamada do método:

```
useEffect(async () => console.warn(await getData()), [])
```

Na verdade não entendi porque tive que aguardar dinovo ao invocar o getData(), visto que no mesmo eu já aguardo, caso alguém queira responder isso é só dizer!!!

De qualquer maneira isso resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Isso que você ta logando é o protótipo de uma promise.

Quando você coloca o prefixo `async` em uma função, ela obrigatoriamente retorna uma promise. O `return` dessa função será então o valor pela qual a promise será resolvida.

Se você quer inserir o valor para qual essa promise resolver em uma variável, você obrigatoriamente tem que usar o await, e para usar o await, precisa estar dentro de uma função async.

Outra opção que você tem é usar o `.then` após chamar a função async, por exemplo...

```js
async getData = () => {
    return "some data";
}

myFunction = () => {
    getData().then(data => console.warn(data));
}

async myOtherFunction = () => {
    const data = await getData(); //uso await porque getData retorna uma promise
    console.warn(data);           //data agora contém o valor pelo qual a promise resolveu
}
```

Esses dois exemplos produzem basicamente o mesmo resultado. Ainda há uma diferença entre elas na maneira no ciclo de execução, mas o resultado é basicamente o mesmo.